# Fatal Error - Allowed Memory - PHP

Tags: php, cmd

Estou com o seguinte problema, ao mandar executar meu script via browser ele funciona tranquilamente e muito rápido, porem ao tentar no `CMD` ele consome toda a memória e da erro.

Via browser: `http://170.30.255.100:88/call_email_gerente_conta.php`

Via cdm:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\iis\PHP\v5.6\php.exe" E:\site\call_email_gerente_conta.php

Erro: Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate
 36 bytes) in E:\site\call_email_gerente_conta.php on line 8
```

Alguma ideia do motivo desse comportamento, meu csv tem apenas 3 linhas.

```
<?php
  $file = fopen('Lista_responsaveis.csv', 'r');
  $i=0;

  while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE)
  {
     $responsavel[$i]=$line[0];
     $i++;
 }
 fclose($file);

 unset($responsavel[0]);

 foreach ($responsavel as $item)
 {
    echo '</br>';
    include("email_gerente_conta.php");
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Qual a versão que está sendo usada na web

Comment: A versao da web é a mesma do CLI

Answer (score -1):

Executar pelo `CLI(Command line interface)` realmente exige mais memória que pelo browser e passa do padrão alocado, logo deves executar o código com um `-d` ou `-define` e alterar o limite de memória -> `memory_limit`

```
php -d memory_limit=128M E:\site\call_email_gerente_conta.php
```

com o parâmetro -d você pode alterar qualquer configuração do php.ini

[Fonte e exemplos](https://haydenjames.io/understanding-php-memory_limit/)

Comment: Ola, continua o mesmo erro

Comment: Você tentou alocar uma quantidade de memória maior? 512MB por exemplo

Comment: Sim, mesma coisa.